# The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, GetLRL) is undefined

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass arrayList intent to the GETLRL class but I am getting this error:

> The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, GetLRL) is       undefined

How can I fix it?

I appreciate any help.

**This code is in the MainActivity:**

```
private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        .
        .
        .

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i : items) {
                    CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(i);

                    if (ch.isChecked()) {
                        int a = Integer.parseInt(ch.getText().toString());
                        selected.add(a);

                    }
                }
                //here is the error
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, GetLRL.this);
                intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("stop_route", selected);
                startActivity(intent);



            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because in your code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GetLRL.this); // <<- Here this refers to View.OnClickListener not an Activity reference
```

From above code line, `this` refers to `onClickListener` and Intent Requires `Application Context` as First argument and use `.class` as Second Argument.

So change your code line like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetLRL.class);
```

Or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getApplicationContext(), GetLRL.class);
```